# Calculating centiles along with minimum and maximum values in R

Tags: r

I'd like to calculate all centiles for a data set along with the minimum and maximum values. I'm comfortable doing this with quartiles, for example:

```
data <- 1:500
quantile(data)
```

Which gives me the following:

```
    0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
  1.00  25.75  50.50  75.25 100.00
```

However, I'm not clear on how to accomplish this for centiles. A search on SO only produced answers concerning centile curves, so after looking at `?quantile` it seems the `probs` argument looks promising. However, when I try the following it produces an error:

```
data <- 1:500
quantile(data, probs = 0:100)

Error in quantile.default(data, probs = 0:100) : 'probs' outside [0,1]
```

Any bump in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation is quite clear on what should be passed to the `probs` parameter.

Comment: Actually the name `probs` is also quite informative... Just saying :)

Comment: You two are right. Long day, and I was having a brain malfunction trying to pass `0:100`. It's clear to me now that it needs to be `0:1` in increments of `0.01`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
quantile(data, probs = (0:100)/100)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or this:

```
quantile(x, probs =seq(0,1,0.1))
```

You can set probabilities by seq   with different steps. For example: 
seq(0,1,0.01) or seq(0.9,1,0.01)

Comment: I think you mean `quantile(x, probs =seq(0,1,0.01))`.